# How to deploy Django application to Heroku - I keep getting error code H10

Tags: python, django, heroku

How can I identify what I am doing wrong here?

```
'''
2021-03-17T15:47:40.537869+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=phil.herokuapp.com request_id=a917acfe-3ff8-4d9b-8ce8-62df15f56b58 fwd="68.48.189.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
'''

'''
2021-03-17T15:47:41.230050+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=phil.herokuapp.com request_id=8cb225e2-c677-48d1-936e-1a5ed8c29904 fwd="68.48.189.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
'''

'''2021-03-17T16:33:48.040804+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=phil.herokuapp.com request_id=69e8e429-e064-42dc-be4d-2c4c7db5ce47 fwd="68.48.189.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
'''

'''
2021-03-17T16:33:48.592375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=phil.herokuapp.com request_id=c26a368c-af03-4604-93a0-13fd5c6be104 fwd="68.48.189.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
'''

'''
2021-03-17T16:44:02.920835+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=phil.herokuapp.com request_id=a3444390-698d-4c77-8998-23bb6a75b04b fwd="68.48.189.95" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
'''
```

Comment: need more info. heroku config file, buildpacks, etc would be helpful

Comment: This error mostly caused by the misconfiguration of Procfile.